# What "configurable" means in Apple

Tags: macbook-pro

I purchased a [MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715?locale=en_US):

It says that:

> 8GB of 1866MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory
>   Configurable to 16GB.

What does *configurable* means here? Can I upgrade the memory to 16GB?

Comment: If you had a 2012 or earlier model, Apple has instructions at  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This term *configurable* refers to the fact that when you order a Mac from Apple you can choose to configure it with more RAM. You cannot do this after purchase yourself, as the RAM is soldered on during the manufacturing process.

Other *configurable* options when buying a Mac usually include the size and/or type of storage, the processor you wish to have, bundled software, and so on. The choices you get also depend on the model of Mac you purchase.